# pointPolygonTest in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use `pointPolygonTest` but I have a problem. My version of OpenCV is 2.2.

I tried to use the code from [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html#point-polygon-test).

I use `findContours` to detect contours in an image. Under OpenCV 2.2 returns a `vector<vector<Point> >`.

The problem is that `pointPolygonTest` accept a `cv::Mat` as an entry. Therefore the code doesn't compile with OpenCV 2.2:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const cv::Mat&’ from expression of type ‘std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >’
```

Under more recent OpenCV versions, the `findContours` function returns `vector<Mat>` so it's easy to pass to `pointPolygonTest` (see the example).

I guess I could convert the `vector< vector<Point> >` to `vector<Mat>`.
Unfortunately the documentation is not very clear about the format.

Does anybody have an advice?

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that pointPolygonTest accept a cv::Mat as an entry.

So why do you use old version of OpenCV? Here's declaration of this method in OpenCV ver. 2.4.1:

```
C++: double pointPolygonTest(InputArray contour, Point2f pt, bool measureDist)
```

As you can see the first parameter is [InputArray](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray) not matrix. From that article:

> You can assume that instead of InputArray/OutputArray you can always
>   use Mat, std::vector<>, Matx<>, Vec<> or Scalar.

So, this means that you can use `std::vector<vector<Point> >` as `InputArray` and so as input to the function `pointPolygonTest`.

Here's simple example of using `pointPolygonTest` (of course in new version):

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Mat src;

findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(size_t i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (pointPolygonTest(contours[i], point, false) > 0)
    {
        //point is inside polygon
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

So just update to the new version.

Alternatively if you want to use it in old version try this casting:

```
    (Mat)contours[i]
```

or using constructor:

```
    Mat(contours[i])
```

Hope it helps.